# Control a desktop webpage through a smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to find a simple example of how to control a webpage on your desktop through a smartphone. Here are two examples: http://unahistoriaquedalavuelta.com/ and http://epic.net/mmxiv/.

This example http://cykod.com/blog/post/2011-08-using-nodejs-and-your-phone-to-control-a-browser-game shows how this can be done through Node.js and Socket.io.

Just wondering if there are other methods how this can be done.

Comment: Define Control. What features are you looking at ?

Comment: @2-Stroker this is all experimental really, what I'd like to look into is stuff like check the phone's orientation, user swipes the phone, user presses a button...then the desktop webpage would react to these events.

Comment: You want to read up on `websockets` http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

Comment: Another great tutorial about how to do it with Node.js and Socket.io: http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/smartphone-remote-control-for-presentations/

And why do you wan't another method? It isn't getting easier than that....